# HighCharts - Trying to create a 'thin' donut chart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am trying to create a thin Donut chart using HighCharts. I've read that If I set `series.innerSize` to be a slightly smaller value than `series.size`, I can get a thin circle. This only works to a certain extent though. No matter how close I make these values, the width of the circle border is still around 10 pixels. I'd like it to be more like three.

Can this be done?

I can get the circle to be thinner if I set the `stroke-width` property of the `.highcharts-series path` selector, but then the two segments of my donut no longer connect.

It's probably easier just to look at the jsfiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/bergonom/3BsYJ/

Note that I need the charts to be fairly small (like less than 100px x 100px), as shown in the fiddle.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the effect you want by specifying the sizes in pixels rather than percentages. e.g.

```
series: [{
        data: testData,
        name: "",
        size: 50,
        innerSize: 47,
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0
    }],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mMH2Z/

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that. Works great, thanks!